# Using ping-pong technique to search for a value in 1D array?

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, cuda, glsl, gpgpu

suppose I want to use a GPU to search for a particular value in an unsorted 1D array of size 2^L, where L is a positive even integer. All the values in the array are **unique**.
Is it possible to use parallel reduction (ping-pong technique) to reduce the search result to a single number?

My intuition tells me that it is possible, but I have no idea of how to start. Can anyone help me out? I am stuck on it for days! Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use the reduction? Do you need to find any occurrence, or the first one, or all of them?

Comment: @Dimaleks: 1st one

Comment: Do you anticipate there be a lot of occurrences? I mean, in the normal scenario you will have an occurrence once every 10 elements, or 10'000?

Comment: @Dimaleks: All the values in the 1D array are unique. I need the 1-D array index of the element if it is found. Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned.

Comment: In CUDA you can run one thread per array element which will write it's index if it found the occurrence into provided device address. If you initialize value by this address to -1 before running the kernel, you'll have the solution

Comment: @Dimaleks, you should write that as the answer. Probably fastest and easiest implementation.

Comment: I tought he wanted to use GPGPU the old way together with ping-pong technique (didn't notice the CUDA tag)

Answer (score 1):

If each one of your threads write either 0 or their (1D index + 1) to the output buffer depending on whether or not they found the searched value, you can run a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) later and find the (1D index + 1) that corresponds to the searched value in the output buffer in O(log n) instead of O(n), which would be the alternative where you simply iterate over the entire thing.